# Using Telprompt:// to make a call (editing message)

Tags: ios, objective-c, call

I have a pretty simple question with perhaps a difficult answer.
Is it possible to edit the message that is thrown when you use "telprompt".

My priority is that i want to make a call and that after that call i want to return to the app itself instead of the Apple phone app.

But when i use a webView or the telprompt method it throws a message. I guess this is for safety reasons which is fine.. But the message only displays a phonenumber and two buttons. I want to add a name or something here.

Is this possible? How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. Period.

(chit chat chit chat to reach characters limit)

Comment: You can however use the `dialNumber:` method of SkankKit’s `SKTelephonyController` (https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/SkankKit.framework/SKTelephonyController.h) if you're not concerned about being rejected by Apple for using private APIs.

Comment: bummer, i hoped this was possible :(